# How to use wtforms validators correctly?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

In my Flask app this Login Form is used, but .loginForm.validate() is always False. Everything except it works great. What is incorrect with this validators?

```py
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[])
    log = SubmitField('Log in')
```

```py
@auth.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main():
    loginForm = LoginForm()
    registerForm = RegisterForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if loginForm.log.data and loginForm.validate():
            print(1)
```

(Without loginForm.validate() it prints 1, validate_on_submit also doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but try this one:

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField(
        'Username',
        validators=[
            DataRequired(),
        ],
    )
    password = PasswordField(
        'Password',
        validators=[
            DataRequired()
        ],
    )
    submit = SubmitField('Log in') 

@auth.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print('valid input')
```